# How to get class with generics types in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a method call like this,

```
public class GenericsTest<T> {

    public static <T> Map<String, T> createMap(Class<? extends Map<String, T>> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Map<String, Integer> result = createMap(TreeMap.class);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error,

```
<T>createMap(java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String,T>>) in test.GenericsTest<T> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<java.util.TreeMap>)
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You can't due to type erasure. In particular, the method signature does not make sense because you are trying to get `T` out even though you are taking in a `Class` for a `Map` with the value parameter as `T`. You will never be able to get the nested type without an existing instance of the object. (You could pass in `(new  HashMap<String, Integer>()).getClass()`, but you still won't be able to get `Integer` back out of that method).

Comment: The createMap() is from a library we use. There must be a way to call that method.

Comment: I question the legitimacy of the returned object. It's supposedly returning an instance of the value parameter, `T`, when being passed in the `Class` for a `Map`, and the method name is `createMap`. None of it makes any sense.

Comment: Try `createMap((Class<? extends Map<String, String>>) TreeMap.class);`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That probably will work, but don't forget the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: The return type is irrelevant. The original method returns a map. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That doesn't work. Getting this error: inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Class<java.util.TreeMap>
required: java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>

Comment: @ZZCoder Change it to: `Map<String, Integer> result = createMap((Class<? extends Map<String, Integer>>) TreeMap.class);`.

Comment: The return type is definitely not irrelevant. You were never getting type `T` out of that method except as a `null` value. However, you can most likely get a `Map` out of it. Eng.Fouad's suggestion (to match the return type with the type being casted) will correct your issue with my originally modified suggestion to supply an instance. The method is abusing the fact that Java's generics are type erased at runtime. The JVM is invisibly doing the casting for you, so by guaranteeing the casts at runtime (either through Suppressions or appropriately matching the data types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> instance = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Integer> map =
    createMap((Class<? extends Map<String, Integer>>)instance.getClass());

map.put("x", 1);

System.out.println("THIS IS x: " + map.get("x"));
```

This will appropriately print out 1. The implementation of the method is most likely

```
try
{
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

A better implementation of their API would be for them to ask you for the type, `T`, and for them to give back a `Map` of their choosing instead of asking you for all of the details. Otherwise, as long as they are not filling in the `Map` with any data, you can instantiate a `Map` with the generic type argument yourself like so:

```
public static <T> Map<String, T> getMap()
{
    return new TreeMap<String, T>();
}
```

You can then access that without a warning:

```
// note the lack of type arguments, which are inferred
Map<String, Integer> instance = getMap();

// alternatively, you could do it more explicitly:
// Map<String, Integer> instance = ClassName.<Integer>getMap();
```

There's really no reason for them to ask you for the `Class` type of your `Map` except to give you back an exact match to the implementation (e.g., if you stick in a `HashMap`, then you will get back a `HashMap`, and if you stick in a `TreeMap`, then you will get back a `TreeMap`). However, I suspect that the `TreeMap` will lose any `Comparator` that it was constructed with, and since that is an immutable (`final`) field of `TreeMap`, then you cannot fix that; that means that the `Map` is not the same in that case, nor is it likely to be what you want.

If they are filling in the `Map` with data, then it makes even less sense. You could always pass in an instance of a `Map` to fill, or have them return a `Map` that you can simply wrap (e.g., `new TreeMap<String, Integer>(instance);`), and they should know which `Map` offers the most utility to the data.

Comment: This runs but with the unchecked warning. There must be a way to call this method without warning. That's the whole purpose of using generics.

Comment: You are right about the purpose, but Java has limited generics because of Type Erasure, which is causing this issue; there are limitations to what you can do without having to coax the compiler into doing it for you. It's probably my least favorite feature of Java because it will be the hardest for them to fix, or replace. .NET has a much more versatile generics system because they are not forgotten at runtime.

After compilation, that map access will become `(Integer)map.get("x")`  because the returned type is actually `Object`.