# How to instantiate a HashMap<K, V>?

Tags: java, generics, persistence

First of all, I'm not an expert of generics, but I attempted to create a class to persist any type of object into a specified path using the following approach.

```
 public class PersistentObject<T> {

  /**
   * Persisted object class.
   */
  private Class<T> clazz;
  /**
   * Persisted object.
   */
  private T object;
  /**
   * Path of the file where the object is persisted
   */
  private String path;

  public PersistentObject(String path, Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.path = path;
    load(); //Load from file or instantiate new object
  }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm not able to use `T` as a class that implement the interface `Map<K, V>`, mainly because of the `clazz` constructor parameter.  Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 PersistentObject<String> test =
      new PersistentObject<String>("path", String.class);

 PersistentObject<HashMap<String, Integer>> test2 =
      new PersistentObject<HashMap<String, Integer>>("path", HashMap<String, Integer>.class); // Compilation error
```

The problem is how can I pass a `Class` object that allows the instantiation of a `HashMap<K, V>`, e.g. `HashMap<String, Integer>`, if there is one?

I guess there is a design flaw in my implementation, some misunderstanding of generics concepts, or both. Any comments or suggestions are really welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what do you need the attribute `clazz`? Maybe you have a [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You can use `HashMap.class` to call your constructor since [type erasure does remove generic types at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). But I doubt that this solves your problem. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554192/how-to-get-class-with-generics-types-in-java) seems to be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a class literal to pass a `Class` object into your `PersistentObject` constructor.  However, generics aren't supported in class literals, because in Java generics is a compile-time feature.  Due to type erasure, the generic type parameters aren't available at runtime, presumably when you plan to use this `Class` object.

Assuming that you need the `Class` object to instantiate a `HashMap` at runtime, the type information isn't available to create a `HashMap<String, Integer>` -- only a `HashMap`.

To get it to compile, you can use an unchecked cast.

```
PersistentObject<HashMap<String, Integer>> test2 =
    new PersistentObject<>("path",
        (Class<HashMap<String, Integer>>) (Class<?>) HashMap.class);
```

Casting to `Class<?>` from a class literal is allowed without a warning, but you'll get a compilation warning about casting that to a `Class<HashMap<String, Integer>>`.  You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to remove the warning.  Just be sure that this unchecked cast is indeed safe for your purposes.

Comment: @João Considering the _Persistent_, you'll the need some other mechanism to indicate the types of the keys and values in the map.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, @rgettman. Casting to a wildcard before the actual needed class was the only thing I didn't try, hehe...

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class PersistentObject<T> {

  /**
   * Persisted object class.
   */
  private Class<T> clazz;
  /**
   * Persisted object.
   */
  private T object;
  /**
   * Path of the file where the object is persisted
   */
  private String path;

  public PersistentObject(String path, Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.path = path;
    //load(); //Load from file or instantiate new object
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    PersistentObject<String> test =
      new PersistentObject<String>("path", String.class);
    PersistentObject<HashMap<String, Integer>> test2 = new PersistentObject<>("path", (Class<HashMap<String, Integer>>) (Class<?>) HashMap.class);
  }
}
```